# How to use dataset of UCI for classification of RVM?

Tags: matlab, rvm, svm

I have downloaded some datasets from UCI for classification of RVM task.However,I am not sure about how to use it.I guess that these datasets must be normalized or do some other job before using it for training and testing.
For example,I have downloaded 'banknote authentication Data Set' on UCI.And use svmtrain in matlab to obtain a svm model(use svm model for testing data and then use rvm codes if result of svm classification is ok).

```
>> load banknote
>> meas = banknote(:,1:4);
>> species = banknote(:,5);
>> data = [meas(:,1), meas(:,2), meas(:,3), meas(:,4)];
>> groups = ismember(species,1);
>> [train, test] = crossvalind('holdOut',groups);
>> cp = classperf(groups);
>> svmStruct = svmtrain(data(train,:),groups(train),'showplot',true);
```

These is what I do in matlab,and get the following message:

```
??? Error using ==> svmtrain at 470
Unable to solve the optimization problem:
Maximum number of iterations exceeded; increase options.MaxIter.
To continue solving the problem with the current solution as the
starting point, set x0 = x before calling quadprog.
```

And here are a part of the dataset(total lines 1372 and use some for training and the rest for testing):

```
3.6216,8.6661,-2.8073,-0.44699,0
4.5459,8.1674,-2.4586,-1.4621,0
3.866,-2.6383,1.9242,0.10645,0
3.4566,9.5228,-4.0112,-3.5944,0
0.32924,-4.4552,4.5718,-0.9888,0
4.3684,9.6718,-3.9606,-3.1625,0
3.5912,3.0129,0.72888,0.56421,0
2.0922,-6.81,8.4636,-0.60216,0
3.2032,5.7588,-0.75345,-0.61251,0
1.5356,9.1772,-2.2718,-0.73535,0
1.2247,8.7779,-2.2135,-0.80647,0
3.9899,-2.7066,2.3946,0.86291,0
1.8993,7.6625,0.15394,-3.1108,0
-1.5768,10.843,2.5462,-2.9362,0
3.404,8.7261,-2.9915,-0.57242,0
```

So, any good advice about this problem?Thank you all for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later to commit.Use scale function to normalization the feature.And if the datasets have too many features,we can use PCA to reduce dimension.